# Is this a valid Answer?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, equivalence-relations

First off, I am quite open to changing the name of the question if anyone has suggestions, so that it might be more accessible and helpful to future mathonaughts.

I need to describe partitions for given equivalence relations.

The following 2 are straight forward but I feel are important to ensure I have a firm grasp of what's meant to be done.

For $x,y \in \mathbb R \ xRy \quad iff \quad x^2=y^2$

$\mathscr P = \{\overline n \in \mathbb R : y=x\}$

For $(x,y)R(u,v) \quad iff \quad x+v=y+u$

$\mathscr P = \{ \overline {(x,y)} \in \mathbb R : u-v = x-y => u=x \land v=y \}$

Am I right so far? The next thing has me somewhat stumped

For $n,m\in \mathbb Z$ nRm iff n and m have he same 10 digits. I've devised an answer as shown below, but I am not certain it is rigorous enough and would greatly appreciate any feedback you are willing to share.

Let $N_n = \{k_i: i \in \mathbb N, 0 < i \le 10, k_i  = \frac {(n \pmod {10^i}) \ - (n\pmod {10^{i-1}})} {10^{i-1}}, \ 10^9 \le n < 10^{10} \}$. => This gives a set for all the digits in the number n.

Let $M_m$ = Same thing as above except for number m

Therefore $\mathscr P = \{ \overline n : 10^9 \le n < 10^{10}, \ 10^9 \le m < 10^{10}, \ s.t.  M_m = N_n \}$ => if I'm not mistaken on notation, $\overline n$ would be the set of all numbers m which contain the same digits as n (albeit in a different order). My one concern is that some sets of $\mathscr P$ might have overlap, but and there is a major place where I could use input... If you hypothetically had $n_1 = 2531 \quad and \quad n_2 = 5321$ but if I'm not mistaken, in the partition, those would wind up being considered the same subset. If you could shed light and give me an idea of how close I am, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your answer on relation $x^2=y^2$ makes no sense. What is $\overline n$ there? I suspect an equivalence class, but represented by what? Also $x^2=y^2$ can be true if $x\neq y$. It should be something like: $\mathscr P=\{\{x,-x\}\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$.

Comment: Also the second case is wrong. Equivalence there means something as pairs of numbers with constant offset.

Comment: it appears I have an inherent misunderstanding of this exercises. I will go back to the drawing board and try to get a firmer grasp

Comment: @Pieter21 this is just a shot in the dark but would the relationship for part 2 be P={ {(y,x)} : x,y are real} ? I think i'm really struggling with this one..

Answer (score 1):

The second one should be something like the collection of pairs with difference $x - y = a$ for all $a$, borrowing the notation of drhab:

$\mathscr P=\{\{\{x, x+a\}\mid x\in\mathbb R\}\mid a\in\mathbb R\}$

I'm not sure if it is easy to write an easy non-verbal notation for the third case if it is just homework, and it needs to be able to handle leading $0$'s.